# Calculate how many Array in the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am now working on a simple AngularJS project, and I have this code:

This is my view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="metering in meterings">
 <td>1</td> 
 <td>{{metering.d.SerialNumber}}</td>                                         
</tr>
```

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('MainCtrl', []).controller('MainController', function($scope,$http,Nerds) { 

    Nerds.get()
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.meterings = data;
        });  
});
```

This is my services:

```
angular.module('NerdService', []).factory('Nerds', ['$http', function($http) {
    return{
        get : function(){
            return $http.get('http://amrse.net/list.json');  //Let's pretend that this path is works fine
        }
    } 
}]);
```

My questions are: 1. How can the number 1 in this table (in the view) changes dynamically?  `<td>1</td>`

2. I want to calculate total array that repeat in `<td>{{metering.d.SerialNumber}}</td>`. Something like: `Total : {{ metering.getTotal() }}`. How can I do that?

Comment: ` Total : {{ metering.getTotal() }}` you can do exactly that. Moreover - you already doing it (`{{metering.d.SerialNumber}}`)

Comment: Yeah, but in my controller doesn't looks right. My controller for metering.getTotal --> $scope.getTotal = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.metering.d.uSN; i++){ 
            total += $scope.metering.d.uSN[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

Comment: seems fine to me , other than i'd do it in more functional style with `[].reduce` , `[].map` etc

Comment: can you post the sample JSON response?

Comment: here, you can see the JSON response here: armse.net/list.json

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

Just simply add these lines of code:

```
<td>{{$index}}</td> 
<td>{{meterings.length}}</td>
```

Thank you! :)